# How to fix 'non-type template argument is not a constant expression' in eigen3?

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen3

I am still new to the Eigen library and C++. I am testing some code and I do not get why this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a = 2;
  const int SIZE_ = a;
  Eigen::Matrix<float, SIZE_, SIZE_> test;
  return 0;
}
```

does not compile, while this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const int SIZE_ = 2;
  Eigen::Matrix<float, SIZE_, SIZE_> test;
  return 0;
}
```

works perfectly fine. How could I change the first code so that it works (i.e. SIZE_ would be initiated by a variable that potentially could have a different value).

Answer (score 8):

You can't. Template arguments must be compile-time constants.

`const int SIZE_ = 2;` is a compile-time constant, there is no possible way `SIZE_` can ever have a value different from 2 here. The compiler knows this and can safely build the type `Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>`.

`const int SIZE_ = someNonConstantExpression;` is not a compile-time constant. It cannot be used in template arguments.

You cannot trick the compiler into accepting run-time values where compile-time values are required, such as in templates. However, Eigen has dynamic matrices (where the size need not be known at compile-time) that you could use instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think @MaxLanghof has cleared the problem, but if you still want the value for the Matrix size to come from another method (but still at compile time), you can use a `constexpr` method like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;

constexpr int getSizeOfMatrix()
{
   return 2*3;
}

int main()
{
  const int SIZE_ = getSizeOfMatrix();
  Eigen::Matrix<float, SIZE_, SIZE_> test;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would really suggest writing `constexpr int SIZE_ = ...` so you immediately get the error (in case `getSizeOfMatrix()` was not `constexpr`) and not only when trying to declare `test`.