# How to Instantiate a Template Class with Parameters at Runtime in C++?

Tags: c++, c++-templates

I'm relatively new to C++ and currently facing a challenge with template instantiation where the template parameter needs to be determined at runtime.

Here's a simplified version of my scenario:

But I stuck at this issue.

```
template <int a>
class ClassA
{
do something with a;
};

int main()
{
  int array[3] = { 2, 2,2};

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {

    ClassA<array[i]> *class_a_instance = new ClassA<array[i]>(constrcutor arguements);
  }
}
```

I understand that C++ requires non-type template parameters like **a** in **ClassA** to be known at compile-time, making **ClassA<array[i]>** illegal.

However, I'm looking for a workaround for the following constraints:

- I can't modify ClassA.
- The values I need to use come from an array or are otherwise only known at runtime.
- I prefer not to write repetitive code manually for each possible case (e.g., ClassA<1>, ClassA<2>, ClassA<3>, ...).

I cannon modify ClassA directly, which isn't an option for me.

Is there a design pattern, language feature, or coding strategy that could provide a clean solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance & Best regards

Comment: [Template arguments must be compile-time constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58523214/12002570)

Comment: It is impossible to instantiate a template at runtime. There is probably some solution to your actual problem, but you've simplified it away.

Comment: If you are desperate, here is a workaround if you can limit the range of allowed `a` values: https://godbolt.org/z/rT6nThc5o

Comment: Array's size must be define only in compile time in c++. You can use other container eg `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @joergbrech Seems to be helpful. I will try to work with a similar approach and see.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of templates is in general a compile time construct.

The simple answer to your question is: You can't instantiate any templates depending on runtime content of variables.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, If you were given a bunch of classes like this from a library, what would you potentially do to use them in a scenario like mine? Printing the code?

Comment: Again: You can't do it! You simply can not write a run time variable inside the template parameter list! The compiler give you the error message which simply tells you, what I said :-) Example: `int a; a=5; X<a> x;` will always give you a compile error!

Comment: @manikantaallam It strongly depends on how are you going to use the variable later. There is no one solution fits all.

Comment: Well, you can generate (an equivalent of) a `switch` to pick the right template parameter. You just need to know all possible values in advance.

Comment: I know values beforehand. I have to fetch them from possibly a JSON file and build the instance(s) - a bigger scenario to be specific.

Comment: Or you can use std::visit with std::variant to get the right object/call selected if this fits to your real problem. In case of bigger non continuous  value ranges you should think of binary search to decrease the needed access time if your compiler will not optimize you hand crafted switch/case code. Or you can template your code, generate a template sorted call vector and access via binary search. All depends on you real use case.